# How to find the rows for dataframe mask

Tags: python, dataframe

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[False, True],[False, False]], columns=['a', 'b'])
```

How to show only the rows (it will be only the first row in this case) instead of showing all rows?

Tried the code below but it shows all rows:

```
df == True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df[df.any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the rows with at least one `True`?

Then use [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
       a     b
0  False  True
```